# Is MySQL Replication what I need?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I am building a R&D website, where I run a lot of proprietary software that I don't want to install on a webserver.  My plan is to setup a master on my local machine hooked to a standard broadband connection and set the MYSQL on the website at some colocation center as a slave to the master.  Does this sound like a good idea?

Comment: Would a replication slave be faster than just a simple database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your connection is down then the website is down.

If you switch master and slave then at least site will be constantly available. If replication delay and out-of-date data is not an issue then this solution is fine.